# How can i stop payment when resource is too high at gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I registered my card and there's many cash in bank.
I have been hacked once before so I lost my free 300$ credits all.
so i'm worrying if I hacked, resource is used too much, then i have to pay money too much..? right?
Is there any solution to prevent about this issue? plz. thanks :)

uhm about alert by write steps(stack overflow's), I tried to make limit line about resource usage.. but there's also the message that "we don't stop server when you even use this service" it looked like just service sending the message for user.

Comment: Secure your account using MFA.

Comment: Also setup billing alerts.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @John Hanley, you can [set budget alerts](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets) in order to control project costs. At any point of time you can [disable billing for a project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#disable_billing_for_a_project), which will consequently and immediately stop any paid service enabled in the project.

Regarding security, @Anuj Kumar provided a clue of what needs to be done with MFA ([Multifactor Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/identity/solutions/enforce-mfa)), it is indeed strongly recommended - if not mandatory - to [secure your account with security keys](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/securing-gcp-account-security-keys).